# Referring to arguments in newcommand not working in math mode

Tags: math-mode, macros, optional-arguments, arguments

I would like to create a command given the arguments `$g,n,d,X$`, generates the output `$\overline{M}_{g,n,d}(X)$`. If no `$g$` is given, I would like the default to be `0`.

What I thought was correct was to write:

```
\newcommand{\modspace}[4][0]{\overline{M}_{#1,#2,#3}(#4)}
```

However the compiler is angry with me for some reason, I get the following error message:

> You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.

What should I do?

Comment: Please show a small complete document that gives the error. Your code block only shows a `\newcommand` and no math mode so can not generate the error, which is from code not shown.

Comment: I receive the error with just this line of code, without even trying to invoke the new command.

Comment: No sorry that is not possible. `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\modspace}[4][0]{\overline{M}_{#1,#2,#3}(#4)}
\begin{document}
\end{document}`  defines the command without error. You must have some code not shown that has a `#` in math mode.

Comment: conversely `\documentclass{article}
\overline{M}_{#1,#2,#3}(#4)}
\begin{document}
\end{document}`  would give two other errors which if you scroll past will eventually give `! You can't use \`macro parameter character #' in math mode.`

Comment: The issue was that I was defining the command after the preamble, switching to before the preamble eliminated the error.

Comment: No that is not the issue, moving the command after the preamble would not give an error, why can you not post a simple 3 line complete document that gives the error?

Answer (score 2):

The code shown does not generate any error, as can be seen by

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\modspace}[4][0]{\overline{M}_{#1,#2,#3}(#4)}


$\modspace{a}{b}{c}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

My guess would be that you had a blank line:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\modspace}[4][0]

{\overline{M}_{#1,#2,#3}(#4)}



\end{document}
```

produces

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.7 {\overline
              {M}_{#1,#2,#3}(#4)}
? 
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.7 {\overline{M}_{#
                    1,#2,#3}(#4)}
?
```

As the blank line is taken as `\par` and is the definition of `\modspace` then it evaluates `{\overline` and gives an error as `\overline` must be in math. If you scroll past this it adds a `$` to recover from the first error, but then sees the `#` in math mode and generates the second error.

Comment: This is not what happened. I've resolved the issue by moving the command to before the preamble but still have no idea why it occurred in the first place, may be some issue with overleaf, the platform I was using to write this.  It may be best to delete this question as I'm not sure how useful this is to anyone.

Comment: as I said I had to guess but it is unrelated to overleaf and the error can not occur from the line shown unless you have an earlier error. if you make a small complete document that produces the error, like the example here I would adjust the answer to match